# Print a certain array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

what I'm trying to do is display some values I get into an array, here is how my array comes:

```
{"latitude":53.4749648,"longitude":-2.2083765,"addresses":["219 Ashton Old Road, , , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester","221 Ashton Old Road, , , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester","Beswick Convenience Store, 217 Ashton Old Road, , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester","Treads, 223 Ashton Old Road, , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester","Wong Wong Bakery, 163 Ashton Old Road, , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester"]}
```

now what I'm trying to display are the values from the "addresses", I'm trying to do a "while", for all the values, and print each of them, each address basicaly, hope I've explained myself well.

Comment: You want `print_r` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking like this?

```
$json = '{"latitude":53.4749648,"longitude":-2.2083765,"addresses":["219 Ashton Old Road, , , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester","221 Ashton Old Road, , , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester","Beswick Convenience Store, 217 Ashton Old Road, , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester","Treads, 223 Ashton Old Road, , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester","Wong Wong Bakery, 163 Ashton Old Road, , , , Manchester, Greater Manchester"]}';
$arr = json_decode ($json, true); 
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr); echo "</pre>";

foreach ($arr['addresses'] as $key=>$val) {
    echo "<br />".$key. ' => '.$val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your variable data contains all the json, can't you just write like

```
foreach($data as $val){ 
   echo $val["address"];
}
```